# How to count number of random date functions in every week at Google Looker Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

**I have random dates data exstracting from Firebase in Google Data Studio, and I want to count them how many times in every week.(Sunday to next Sunday)**

So the data looks like this now

| No. | Random_Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/02/02 |
| 2 | 2023/02/03 |
| 3 | 2023/02/06 |
| 4 | 2023/02/13 |
| 5 | 2023/02/14 |
| 6 | 2023/02/15 |

And I want to count the "Random_Dates" function in each week like this.

| No. | Random_Dates | CountinEachWeek |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023/02/02 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023/02/03 | 2 |
| 3 | 2023/02/06 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023/02/13 | 3 |
| 5 | 2023/02/14 | 3 |
| 6 | 2023/02/15 | 3 |

As you can see, No.1 and 2 is in twice a week *2023/01/29(SUN) to 2023/02/05 (Next SUN).

No.3 is once a week *2023/02/05(SUN) to 2023/02/12(Next SUN)
and No.4-6 is three times a week *2023/02/12(SUN) to 2023/02/19 (Next SUN).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to count them how many times in every week.(Sunday to next Sunday)

###### ■ Calculated Column

First, add *new calculated field* `week_start` like below

```
DATETIME_TRUNC(Random_Dates, WEEK)
```

[image]

- [**DATETIME_TRUNC** in Looker Studio Help](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9729685?hl=en&ref_topic=7583292)

###### ■ Blend Data

Using `week_start`, you can count the occurrences of each week and left-join the result of aggregation with original table using *Blend Data* functionality in Looker Studio.

[image]

[image]

###### ■ Result

You can see the *count* of each week in the report like below.

[image]